# Setting predicate based on multiple entities using core data

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I have two tables `oldaddress` and `newaddress` with common field `personID`. I have to get details of `personID` from `newaddress` which exists in `oldaddress` also. How to set entity and predicate for the same in core data?

equivalent query is

```
select a.personID  from new address a, oldaddress b where a.personID=b.personID
```

Comment: It can be done, but you should think about rethinking the model. [Core Data is an object graph manager and not a database!](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html). A more Core Data'ish way would be to define two entities *Person* and *Address*, with relationships *oldaddress* and *newaddress* between them.

Answer (score 3):

You have not grasped the essence of Core Data. As pointed out by Martin R, it is an object graph, not a database.

What you describe is a join table operation, something that is modelled in Core Data via so-called relationships, eliminating the need for foreign keys such as `personID`.

Also, to create different identities that represent the same kind of object is also bad practice.

Thus, your model should look something like this:

```
Address <<------>> User
```

and `Address` should have a boolean property like `isOld`.

Your predicate becomes extremely simple when fetching `User`s.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"addresses.@count = 2"];
```

Alternatively, you can have two one-to-many relationships from `User` to `Address` if you prefer.

```
User.oldAddress <<-----------> Address
User.newAddress <<-----------> Address
```

with a predicate like this

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"oldAddress != NULL && newAddress != NULL"]
```

Comment: + 1 That is what the topic starter should do.